# Property 'Item' does not exist on type 'typeof Accordion'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-bootstrap

I have this Accordion component from react-boostrap.
The code is as follows:

```
import React, { Component, FormEvent } from "react";
import {
  Card,
  Col,
  Container,
  FormControlProps,
  Modal,
  Row,
  Accordion
} from "react-bootstrap";

....
....
....
getInvoicesSelectionModal() {
    return (
      <Modal
        show={this.state.showInvoicesSelection}
        centered={true}
        onHide={this.handlePolicySelectionClose}
      >
        <Modal.Header
          closeButton={true}
        >
          <Modal.Title style={{ color: "white" }}>Select Invoices</Modal.Title>
        </Modal.Header>
        <Modal.Body>
          <div>
            <Accordion>
              <Accordion.Item eventKey="0">
                <Accordion.Header>Accordion Item #1</Accordion.Header>
                <Accordion.Body>
                 2
                </Accordion.Body>
              </Accordion.Item>
              <Accordion.Item eventKey="1">
                <Accordion.Header>Accordion Item #2</Accordion.Header>
                <Accordion.Body>
                2
                </Accordion.Body>
              </Accordion.Item>
            </Accordion>

          </div>
        </Modal.Body>
      </Modal>
    );
  }
```

But I get the following error:

TypeScript error in "Filename.tsx"

Property 'Item' does not exist on type 'typeof Accordion'.

> <Accordion.Item eventKey="0">

Comment: Just ran into this problem too.  If you look at the node_modules/react-bootstrap/Accordion.d.ts / js files you can see Accordion.Item isn't imported anywhere (as far as I can tell).

However, you can see that there is an AccordionItem.d.ts file and it exports a component called AccordionItem.  This isn't the correct solution, but you can import it via import AccordionItem from 'react-bootstrap/esm/AccordionItem'.

Correct solution though is to find if AccordionItem is exported as Accordion.Item.  If not, this probably warrants an issue on their github.